# $A, B$ in Jordan normal form, $A \neq B$, is it possible that $A$ is similar to $B$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, equivalence-relations, jordan-normal-form

Let $A, B \in M(n \times n, \mathbb{K})$ be some matrices in Jordan normal form with $A \neq B$ (even after reordering of the jordan blocks). Is it still possible that $A$ is similar to $B$?

If think, if they both were in Frobenius normal form it would be impossible that $A$ is still possible to $B$, but how about the Jordan normal form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Uniqueness

Comment: @Fan Maybe I misunderstand something, but I think the paragraph shows, that the Jordan normal form of $A$ is unique (up to the order of the Jordan blocks), but does not say something about the similarity of two matrices $A, B$ with the same Jordan normal form. English is not my first language and I may misunderstand something though..

Comment: Two matrices in Jordan normal form are similar iff they are both the Jordan normal form of the same matrix.

Comment: @stewbasic _iff they are both the Jordan normal form of the same matrix_. I don't think this is right. There are many matrices with the same Jordan normal form. Therefore you can't decide if two matrices in Jordan normal form are the Jordan normal form of the same matrix. The only thing you see is, whether they are of the same form (up to permutation of the jordan blocks).

Comment: @user7802048 To be more precise, say that $A$ is "the" Jordan normal form of $X$ if $A$ is in Jordan normal form and similar to $X$. My claim is that if two matrices $A,B$ are in Jordan normal form, then $A,B$ are similar iff there exists $X$ such that $A,B$ are both Jordan normal forms of $X$ (for $\Rightarrow$, just take $X=A$). Fan's link says that the latter happens iff $A,B$ differ only by permutation of the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\text{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$ act on itself by conjugation. Then the orbits of this action are the similarity classes. Inside of each orbit, there is a matrix in Jordan normal form, with $k$ Jordan blocks of sizes $i_1\geq i_2\geq \dots\geq i_k$. Call this matrix $J$. Assuming $i_1\ne i_k$, one could rearrange these blocks, (remaining in Jordan normal form) and have a matrix $J'\ne J$.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be similar (if we assume equality up to ordering blocks). One argument is that one can determine the number of Jordan blocks for eigenvalue $\lambda$ from the dimensions of the nullspaces of $(A-\lambda)^k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots$.

These dimensions however are obviously invariant under similarity. Thus it is a genuine canonical form.

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&1&0\\0&\lambda_1&0\\0&0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_2&0&0\\0&\lambda_1&1\\0&0&\lambda_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @AlexClark yes, this is an example. Reordering the blocks of course keeps the matrices similar.

Comment: Oh right, I hadn't refreshed the page since he added the 'after reordering'. I agree with you.